# Orange links in Wordpress Backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I am starting to find something strange in the backend of our WordPress sites and wondered if anyone here know of a fix.

All the links have turned Orange. Only in two of our sites.  I thought it may have been a plugin, so I have deactivated them all but nothing, the links are still Orange.

I have done a load Google searchs but nothing has come up.

Does anyone have any thoughts.

Comment: Any markup? Examples? We can't help you at all depending only on _Orange links_ knowledge.

Comment: It might be you have included wp_enque_script or styles in admin section too. Or if u didnt do anything with wp_enque_script or styles then it must be plugin. Not only deactivate plugin try delete them. Some plugins left crap behind.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me.  Using FireBug this is what comes up in the CSS
a {
    color: #F7941F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a, #adminmenu a, #the-comment-list p.comment-author strong a, #media-upload a.del-link, #media-items a.delete, #media-items a.delete-permanently, .plugins a.delete, .ui-tabs-nav a {
    color: #21759B;
}

The last color has a line through it, I can add !important by it but where would I put the CSS Code to override the a?

Thanks